# React not re-rendering when state changed from hook

Tags: reactjs

Edit: Thanks for the help everyone. I needed to change the reference of the array and fixed it by doing:

```
setData([...sorted])
```

---

I am currently rendering out a list of tasks. This is a snippet of my return function within a functional component:

```
const [ data, setData ] = useState( mockData )

<tbody>
{ data.map(d => <TaskItem key={d.claimable} task={d}/>) }
</tbody>
```

When I click on a certain button on the page, the dataset gets sorted and I call `setData(sortedData)`

For some reason, the table isnt being re-rendered with the sorted data. Is there something I did wrong here?

This is the sort function:

```
function filterByContactAmount():void {
        let sorted = data.sort((a:any, b:any) => {
            let aTimesContacted:number = a.data.person.contact.list.reduce((acc:number, val:any):number => acc + val.history.length, 0)
            let bTimesContacted:number = b.data.person.contact.list.reduce((acc:number, val:any):number => acc + val.history.length, 0) 

            if ( aTimesContacted > bTimesContacted ) {
                return 1
            }

            if ( bTimesContacted > aTimesContacted ) {
                return -1
            }

            return 0;
        })

        console.log(sorted)
        setData(sorted)
    }
```

Comment: show how you are sorting the data

Comment: @BlackHole Added the sort in

Comment: Can you post link to codesandbox with your code? Let us debug it.

Comment: @loelsonk Alright gimme a sec

Comment: @HMR it's okay to correct your comment with additional comments, when you delete your mistakes the rest of the conversation becomes confusing. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are using the same ref of the array, you need set the new data with

```
setData(old => "sorted data");
```

to change the reference of the state and it updates

```
function filterByContactAmount():void {
        let sorted = data.sort((a:any, b:any) => {
            let aTimesContacted:number = a.data.person.contact.list.reduce((acc:number, val:any):number => acc + val.history.length, 0)
            let bTimesContacted:number = b.data.person.contact.list.reduce((acc:number, val:any):number => acc + val.history.length, 0) 

            if ( aTimesContacted > bTimesContacted ) {
                return 1
            }

            if ( bTimesContacted > aTimesContacted ) {
                return -1
            }

            return 0;
        })

        console.log(sorted)
        setData(old => [...sorted]) // Sorted is the new state sorted
    }
```

Comment: Bit confused with this bit.  Old refers to the inital array and "sorted data" referes to the sorted array? So it would be: `setData(data => sorted)`?

Comment: @Syn i updated the code, you need destructuring the data `setData(old => ...sorted)`

Comment: you can also do `setData(sorted.slice())`

Comment: Array.sort returns the same array reference, so the line `let sorted = data.sort` doesn't create a new reference. `sorted === data` would be `true`

Comment: Still mutating state, very inefficient way to sort and `setData(old => [...sorted])` is not needed, could just ast well use `setData([...sorted])`

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating sate, the other answer is probably not the best because you are still mutating state and then setting state with a copy of the already mutated value.

The sort function can also be optimized. Maybe try the following:

```
function filterByContactAmount() {
  let sorted = data
    .map(d => ({//map shallow copies the array
      ...d,//shallow copies the item
      sortedNum: d.data.person.contact.list.reduce(//do this once for every item, not for every time sort callback is called
        (acc, val) => acc + val.history.length,
        0
      ),
    }))
    .sort((a, b) => a.sortedNum - b.sortedNum);

  console.log(sorted);
  setData(sorted);
}
```

Comment: I would agree, it's better not to mutate the state.

Comment: @HMR I do think my sort function is kinda iffy but after trying your method, I get an error stating `this expression is not callable` over the `reduce`

Comment: @Syn I copied my code in the [typeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAbKBTATgIQJ4DCCUAhtAIIC2c4UAFAJSIDeAUIoqhlIgM5xZMAE0QBeREJKl2HRADpKJAA50RogHyI6zAPQ7FSvgAsSqVHADuiCHCUwMvRFCMZEJLFhJ4Zs+XLlCADR6vCZmlta29o7OrjCYlD6y-IIYQgByIJQAXBIBUiRyStj8YHI2YKTQcqgwvFByWGkgEBh0ekJwTkZ1iAityAKIGABu2HiI8RiUgYhgcDzAQ6PjTjCUrik8EKaoAEZkANaTjjtmaUm+dGQQsyOmTBpuEBCIANSI96hyPfUCeDUMGAAObOQKXWQABghDHBvgAvgwGEk5Fs6NdZntHppCls0plKIgALSIPaogTCAkMADcrBkFX4XBqcGBdDxQhpMl43AAIgU2RS0pz4awgA) and got no compile errors. Can you update your question with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is located under `d.claimable`, I suppose it is `boolean` variable type. You must know that every `key` prop must be *unique*. Check if you have for example`.id` property, if not add it.

Uniqueness of key prop is very important during reconciliation process.

> Unique identifier with a group of children to help React figure out which items have changed, have been added or removed from the list. It’s related to the “lists and keys” functionality of React described here.

Very nice [article](https://indepth.dev/inside-fiber-in-depth-overview-of-the-new-reconciliation-algorithm-in-react/) about reconciliation.

```
<tbody>
{ data.map(d => <TaskItem key={d.claimable} task={d}/>) }
</tbody>
```

Comment: claimable is actually a 5 digit id. I tried adding an index to the map and setting key as the index but it didnt change